# How to download sqlite database to Android device programmatically

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to download an sqlite database programmatically from a URL.  I've tried the following:

[How to download an SQLite database from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162194/downloading-a-sqlite-database)

But it seems to run extremely slow compared to when I download the same file using wget on my development PC running on the same wi-fi connection.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a fairly pathetic download example. Never download a byte at a time.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am open to all new suggestions.

Comment: Searching `java httpurlconnection download example` in your favorite search engine will turn up many examples that download more than a byte at a time, like http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url and http://www.androidsnippets.com/download-an-http-file-to-sdcard-with-progress-notification.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending your class from AsyncTask.

Override `doInBackground()`. In that do the downloading part.

Override `onPostExecute()`. Write other operations that need to be performed after downloading is finished.

Note that result of `doInBackground()` is passed on to `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: there are a good example of  [that](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521)