# Getting local sqlite database from android

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite, appcelerator

I can successfully upload the sqlite file from iOS to server, however having trouble with android, getting a `TiBlob: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Resources/db_name` error. To open the database i use `var backDatabase = Ti.Database.open('db_name');` i am adding this to the post in the HTTP Client.

```
file : OS_IOS ? backDatabase.getFile() : Ti.Filesystem.getFile("./db_name"),
```

So i guess the question is what can i use to get the file in android?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to download from a server a SQLite database programming with Android, is it that?

I think this is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162385/6133630

Do not use any library, simply take the InputStream that returns the connection and copy byte to byte in s3db file.

Comment: sorry for miscommunication i am trying to get the database from the android  device to the server. i just need to get the file.

Answer (score 0):

> On Android, the database is created on the internal storage (you could
>   move it, or use the install procedure to put it on external storage).
>   The standard location on internal storage is
>   **/data/data/com.example.yourappid/databases/dbname**

Docs [here](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database-section-29004901_WorkingwithaSQLiteDatabase-Creatingadatabase)

Or if you are using SDK 5.4.0+, you can actually use the `file` property to get the db file.

Docs [here](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database.DB-property-file)